# df-statfs in FUSE filesystem

Tags: c, filesystems, fuse

I am writing a code for ramdisk in FUSE. After I mount my ramdisk (its size I specify as an argument), I wish to use df -h to see if the space occupied by my ramdisk is the same as the size that I had mentioned as an argument.

For this, I used statfs() function like the one given in example fusexmp.c in the "examples" folder inside fuse-2.9.7 :

```
static int ramdisk_statfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *stbuf)
{
 int res;
 res = statvfs(path, stbuf);
 if (res == -1)
 return -errno;

return 0;
}
```

However, the size I get in the output of "df -h" command is not the size that I mention while mounting my ramdisk.

For example, suppose I mount my ramdisk with :

```
./ramdisk /mnt/ram 2
(where 2 is the size I specify for my ramdisk.)
```

After this, I use "df -h" and I get :

```
Filesystem      Size    Used Avail Use% Mounted on

ramdisk          46G  5.8G   37G  14% /mnt/ram 
(but this is not the size specified by me above for my ramdisk.)
```

After this I use "free -h" to view free RAM, and I get :

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1.7G       806M       954M       5.5M        85M       296M
-/+ buffers/cache:       424M       1.3G
Swap:         3.9G         0B       3.9G
```

If I dont use the statfs() function in my filesystem code, and I use "df -h /mnt/ram" , I get :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

ramdisk          0     0     0     0   /mnt/ram
```

I wish to ask if the implementation of statfs() given above is wrong? How should the code be written so that "df -h" shows the correct memory values?

Comment: `statvfs` for `/mnt/ram` will give the stats of the fs where that folder is (probably `/` but can also be `/mnt`)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `int statfs(const char*, struct statvfs*)` you can set the values which will be shown in `df`. Example:

```c
static int ramdisk_statfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *stbuf) {
    stbuf->f_bsize  = 4096; // block size
    stbuf->f_frsize = 4096; // fragment size
    stbuf->f_blocks = 1024; // blocks

    return 0; // assume no errors occurred, just return 0
}
```

Output of `df`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
test            4.0M  4.0M     0 100% /home/antoni/c/fuse/mnt
```

However, this example is not complete (you see `Avail` is still zero), all fields you can set are:
`f_bsize`, `f_frsize`, `f_blocks`, `f_bfree`, `f_bavail`, `f_files`, `f_ffree`, `f_favail`, `f_fsid`, `f_flag` and `f_namemax`.

For more info google 'struct statvfs'.